# using python nonzero function inside array brackets

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm looking at the linked GitHub repository and working through the MLA machine learning book, and stumbled across this bit of code and don't understand what's going on here. What is happening here? Is there a better, more explicit way of writing this bit of python?

https://github.com/KUpypy/Past/blob/fd981bfcc3599914be71d38f0412ef2edbcf6046/MLA/(MLA)%20Chp10/(MLA)%20Chp10_Grouping%20unlabeled%20items%20using%20k-means%20clustering.ipynb

```
bestClustAss[nonzero(bestClustAss[:,0].A == 1)[0], 0] = len(centList) 
bestClustAss[nonzero(bestClustAss[:,0].A == 0)[0], 0] = bestCentToSplit
```

This function is throwing the following error:

```
local variable 'bestClustAss' referenced before assignment
```

My thought was something like this:

```
if(nonzero(bestClustAss[:,0].A == 1)
     bestClustAss ....... = len(cenList)
if(nonzero(bestClustAss[:,0].A == 0)
     bestClustAss ....... = bestCentToSplit
```

But I'm still too new to python to figure this out on my own.

Comment: You don't show how `bestClustAss` was created.  What is it?  The error implies that it hasn't been created yet, or that there's a name error.  I don't think your rewrite will solve that issue.

Comment: In the linked code, in `In [14]`, `bestClustAss` is created inside a loop and `if` expression.  Without getting into details I can imagine cases were it doesn't get created, producing this error after the loop.